# How to empty a Python dict without doing my_dict = {}?

Tags: python, dictionary

If the `my_dict` variable is global, you can't do:

```
my_dict = {}
```

that just create a new reference in the local scope.

Also, I found disgusting using the `global` keyword, so how can I empty a dict using its methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `clear()` method?

[**Documentation**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) - (docs.python.org)

Answer (score 3):

you mean like `.clear()` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

my_dict.clear()